# I want to change the cwd and ling with mention file name using open to just read the file but shows the below error

Tags: python

I am using open to link file after change the CWD, but I'm getting following  error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Ahmed.sriea\\Desktop\\tables\\Ahmed.text'
```

Code:

```
import os 
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.path.abspath(__file__)) 
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) ch=os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Ahmed.Sriea\Desktop\tables') 
print(os.getcwd())
myfile= open(r'C:\Users\Ahmed.sriea\Desktop\tables\Ahmed.text')
```

Comment: Obvious question: does that file exist? Should the extension be "txt" not "text" ?

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, no? The file doesn't exist. Check if you spelled it correctly. Does it really have the extension `.text` rather than `.txt`?

Comment: thanks brother @Rup after changing the extension to  txt the code is  running well